# What is being printed? C++ pointer to an integer

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have the following (very simple) code:

```
int* pInt = new int(32);

std::cout<< pInt << std::endl;  //statement A
std::cout<< *pInt << std::endl; //statement B
std::cout << &pInt << std::endl; //statement C
```

So here's what I **think** I am doing (I have learned that in C++ I am rarely ever doing what I think I am doing):

1. Creating a pointer to an integer and calling it pInt
2. statementA prints the address of the value '32'
3. statementB prints the integer value that is being pointed to by my pointer (which is done because I dereference the pointer, thus giving me access to what it is pointing to).
4. statementC prints the address of the pointer itself (not the address of the integer value '32').

Is all of this correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second statement is wrong. You allocate a new int off the heap. The compile-time constant "32" does not have an address, and therefore you cannot take it. You create an int whose value is 32. This is not the same thing.

```
int* pInt1 = new int(32);
int* pInt2 = new int(32);
```

pInt1 and pInt2 are not equal.

Oh, one last thing- C++ is a pretty strongly typed language, and it's pretty unnecessary to prefix variable names with type data. This is called Hungarian Notation, it's very common in Microsoft C libraries and samples, but generally unnecessary here.

Comment: If the variable was defined as int *value = 32; you would be correct. However Including the constant in the constructor makes it an object. If you did that then the variable would be optimized to a const int*.

Comment: what do you mean by "makes it an object"?

Comment: It's a very subtle distinction, but for complete understanding it's necessary to point it out. I think the correct wording would be "2. statementA prints the address of an `int` which contains the value '32'".

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I fixed my post to reflect your statement. @DeadMG: If for instance your code was written, I could express the equality of the values that are being pointed to this way: (*pInt1 == *pInt2). Is this correct?

Comment: @Storm Kiernan: Yes, that's correct, and your edited statement is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

- Print the memory address of pInt, which points to a region of memory (4 bytes) that contains the value 32:

`std::cout<< pInt << std::endl;  //statement A`

- Print the content of that memory address:

`std::cout<< *pInt << std::endl; //statement B, which should print 32`

- Print the memory address of the pointer itself:

`std::cout << &pInt << std::endl; //statement C`

Answer (score 0):

Statement B prints the value of the object that pInt points to. It points to an int with the value 32, so it prints 32.

Statements A and C are undefined. The object being printed in both cases is a pointer, which at the machine level is a memory address. Most compilers will print a hexadecimal number, although there is no guarantee that it will do so. The value will also depend on where the objects are stored. For example, g++ in 32 bit Windows Vista on my computer prints:

```
0x900ee8
32
0x22ff1c
```

Borland prints:

```
016E33B0
32
0012FF50
```

Visual C++ prints

```
00131D10
32
0028FE24
```

You will probably get different results. The first number is the address allocated by new int() from the heap and saved in pInt. It allocated a 4 byte array, stored the number 32 there and stored the address in pInt. The second number is the value stored, interpreted as an int. The third number is the address (on the stack) of pInt.